# Add a feature to Join site from Android app

Tags: feature-request, support, android-app

I haven't been able to find a way to join a site without going to a question and then trying to comment. At that point it asks if I would like to join the site. I'd there a way to join a site in the Android app without having to try to comment on the question?

Answer (score 4):

There is currently no way to explicitly join a site on the Android application. Any interaction you try to do with the site: Asking a question, commenting, answering, voting, so on, will allow you to join the site before fulfilling the action.

Comment: Comment button is not available, posting Q/A gives error "The account associated with the access_token does not have a user on the site". The only way is to try voting on posts.

Comment: @Pandya at this point, the app is totally broken. Even notifications stop working once you switch to new device.